# Вложенные списки в с++

Tags: c++, list

Недавно я начал изучать с++ и столкнулся с проблемой, для решения которой нужны вложенные списки. список должен выглядеть примерно так: [ [1,2], [3,6], [8,9] ]
На питоне я могу сделать так:

```
my_list = []
in_list = [2,3]
my_list.append(in_list)
```

И выводим: print(my_list[0][1])
А как можно такое реализовать на с++?

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> vect;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::list<std::list<int> > mainList;

std::list<int> subList1 = {1, 2};
std::list<int> subList2 = {3, 4};
std::list<int> subList3 = {5, 6};

mainList.push_back(subList1);
mainList.push_back(subList2);
mainList.push_back(subList3);
```

Можно использовать **std::vector** вместо **std::list** как вам уже написали в комментариях. Зависит что лучше подойдет для той задачи которую вы выполняете

Comment: А как менять значения sublistов и cout'ить их?

Comment: @notUsver Проходитесь for'м по основному списку, потом внутри for'а проходитесь еще одним по саблисту. По идее это отдельный вопрос уже. Потому что можно не только for использовать. Вам нужно почитать документацию как работать со списками https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: Спасибо! Отметил ваш ответ принятым